# Reverse repr function in Python

Tags: python, repr

if I have a string with characters ( `0x61` `0x62` `0xD` ), the `repr` function of this string will return `'ab\r'`.

Is there way to do reverse operation: if I have string `'ab\r'` (with characters `0x61` `0x62` `0x5C` `0x72`), I need obtain string `0x61` `0x62` `0xD`.

Comment: You can use [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) and [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord), but `'\r'` isn't two characters. And `'\r'` is [`0xd`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d/index.htm), not [`0x13`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/13/index.htm).

Comment: I use repr(that converts \r to two characters), becouse I need to see all special characters, and I need function, that are reverse to repr, becouse I need to enter the special characters in forman \ch.
Yes, 0xD of course, sorry for mistake

Comment: it is not two characters if I write str="ab\r", but is when I read it from my GUI interface

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> s = repr("ab\r")
>>> s
"'ab\\r'"
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(s)
'ab\r'
```

Comment: Your code works, but not in my situation(( I need smth next:

    >>> s="ab\\r"
    >>> s
    'ab\\r'
    >>> print(s)
    ab\r
    >>> literal_eval(s)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
        node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
      File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
        return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
      File "<unknown>", line 1
        ab\r
           ^
    SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: @user3479125 you don't have enough quotes - note that there are two pairs (one single, one double: `"'...'"`) in `s` in my example. Otherwise, `literal_eval` can't evaluate it as a string.

Comment: Why not just `eval`?

Comment: @SeF See here: [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/10752293).