# Python IDLE won't "restart"

Tags: python, runtime, python-idle

I think this is very strange, I'm trying to test a script I wrote with IDLE by pressing F5 but nothing happens (not even errors). In the runtime window, there is no `===RESTART===` at all. I'm able to directly execute commands but it seems like the runtime didn't load my script at all. I'm afraid my file is too long to post here but does anyone know what could keept the Python runtime from loading my script? 
BTW: Other file are loaded as usal.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php try this one. might help. I use pycharm personally.

Comment: does using the menu work? `run -> Run Module`

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: No, I'm using Linux turning it off and on won't do it.

Comment: The are no reports on the tracker about an issue like this.  I have very occasionally had key bindings in Windows and IDLE get messed up, solved by rebooting.  I did not see an answer as to whether the menu worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php I found out that while trying to make a `\x01` string by `"\x0" + "1"` an error occurs which isn't displayed by my runtime. Well it was a try.

Comment: and IDLE did not give you `(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: truncated \xXX escape`?

Comment: and to actually do `"\x0" + "1"` you would need to use [raw string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/301076/5827215) in combination with [evaluating the string itself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24886425/5827215), in other words you could do `ast.literal_eval("'"+r"\x0"+r"1"+"'")` to join the numbers together, although I assume you know about `chr(1)` at this point.