# New line for output in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner and I want to make a simple program that would take an input and print it back in new line. This is how my code looks.

```
a=input("enter: ")
print(a)
```

output what i get:

```
enter: python\ncode
python\ncode
```

expected output:

```
enter: python\ncode
python
code
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing a text with \n in it, with a real \n output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965689/replacing-a-text-with-n-in-it-with-a-real-n-output)

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy thankyou! it works. but i also want to know why does it not work if "\n" is given in input, like is it forbidden to be used in input. also hope you don't mind my english

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this problem based on another Stack Overflow thread: [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python)
Decode the string before printing like this

```
    >>> a = input('Enter: ')
    Enter: python\ncode
    >>> a
    'python\\ncode'
    >>> print(a)
    python\ncode
    >>> print(bytes(a, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape"))
    python
    code
    >>>
```